# Como hago para fijar un boton al final de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, botón

Tengo este ejemplo en plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/z9uszzOC32qgq1oPxGxG?p=preview

Es una tabla con datos que al final tiene un boton "Mostrar mas..." con el que le doy mas datos a la tabla.
 El problema es que esta tabla es scrolleable, lo que intento hacer de alguna manera es que ese boton quede "fijo" o sea que cuando se scrollee horizontalmente se mantenga siempre visible el texto "Mostrar Mas..." en el centro del boton. 
Ya que si tiene muchos datos y se scrollea se pierde. No se si me explico, ese boton Mostrar mas siempre tiene que ser visible al usuario a pesar que scrollee mucho.

Si me pueden ayudar agradecido!
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podrías poner el botón en una posición y actualizar la posición con javascript cuando se hace scroll:

```js
$(function(){
  $('.panel').scroll(function(){
    $('.btnMas').css({ 'left': $(this).scrollLeft()});
  });
});
```

```css
.btnMas{
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous"><!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  
    <div class="panel col-mx-12" style="overflow:auto;width:400px;height:180px;">
      <div style="display:grid;">
     <div id="divTableMain" class="col-mx-12" >
      <div class="col-mx-12" style="width:100%" >
    <table border="1" style="">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>col1</th>
          <th>col2</th>
          <th>col3</th>
          <th>col4</th>
          <th>col5</th>
           <th>col6</th>
          <th>col7</th>
          <th>col8</th>
          <th>col9</th>
          <th>col10</th>
              <th>col11</th>
          <th>col12</th>
          <th>col13</th>
          <th>col14</th>
          <th>col15</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
            <tr>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
          <td>blabla</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
      <button class="btnMas" title="Cargar más datos">
                    Mostrar más...
                </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por responder, esa solucion la analizamos pero no me dejaron implementarla, me dijeron que busque otra forma de hacerlo. gracias de todos modos

Comment: Pero ¿cual es la pega? ¿que debe ocupar todo el ancho? ¿que debe estar en otra posición? ¿que no debe precisar de javascript?

Comment: En verdad el problema que surge cuando implemento esa solucion es este: https://plnkr.co/edit/z9uszzOC32qgq1oPxGxG?p=preview                                                      Para probar el bug tenes que apretar 1 vez el boton + Datos, llevar la barra de scroll hasta el final y luega apretar - Datos. Vas a ver un efecto medio raro con la barra de scroll y la tabla cuando quitas toda esa cantidad de columnas, ese efecto se da por la funcion del scroll que se esta usando para mover el boton